# Bad characters in file output

Tags: c++, arrays, file-io

Writing a preorder traversal of a optimal binary search tree to a .txt file recursively.
The code is:

```
 void PrintTree(int i, int j, int space)
{
    if(i < j)
    {
        outfile.write("", space++);
        outfile<<A[Rt[i][j]]<<endl;
         PrintTree(i, Rt[i][j], space);
         PrintTree(Rt[i][j] + 1, j, space);
    }
    else
    {
        outfile.write("",space);  //This line
         outfile.write("-\n",2);      
    }
}
```

This output works for small trees, like up to 7-10.  More than that gives me bad some bad characters, and I can't seem to find where they are coming from.

```
F

 A

  -

  C

   B

    -

    -

   E

    D

    Ì-

    Ì-

    -

 K

  I

   H

    G

    Ì-

    Ì-

    -

   J

    -

    -

  M

   L

    -

    -

   O

    N

    Ì-

    Ì-

    -
```

Is an example of the output I am getting.  I have no idea what the 'Ì' characters are from in that code.

```
const int n = 15;
char A[n] = {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N',  'O'};
int P[n] = {150, 25, 50, 25, 50, 125, 25, 75, 75, 50, 150, 75, 50, 25, 50};

 int S[n+1][n+1] = {};
 int Rt[n+1][n+1] = {};
```

These are all my initial arrays.(above)

```
 PrintTree(0, n, 0);
```

Is my initial call to print tree.  S[][] is the array in the file I linked in comments...it is the numbers.   Rt[][] contains numbers corresponding to A[n].  So, Rt[i][j] = 1; maps to A[1] which is 'B'.

The arrays themselves are not being accessed out of bounds, and it only happens when 'space' becomes 4 or greater, so that would be 4 levels deep into the recursion.

Comment: I think you're going to need to post some more information. You have an array `A` and an array `Rt`; you don't show the declarations for either. Nor do you show the code that loads these arrays, but you're using multiple levels of indexing to access them. You need, therefore, to show the code that loads these arrays. I note that your problem is not self-evidently file I/O; it may be more to do with the output of the data from memory (or the loading of data into memory — which might perhaps be file I/O related, but is more likely related to all the index numbers in `A[Rt[i][j]]`).

Comment: The character 'Ì` is Unicode U+00CC, LATIN CAPITAL LETTER I WITH GRAVE, or 0xCC in Latin-1 (ISO 8859-1).  It is, most likely, garbage triggered by out of bounds array accesses, assuming you don't have the letter in your data file.  I've now seen some code updates; I'll see if I can make head or tail of it.  Since `A` and `Rt` appear to be global variables, you're probably not making as good use of C++'s encapsulation facilities as is possible — but equally, you may not have reached that stage in your learning.

Comment: Sorry, the .cpp file is now available at the same hyperlink.  Hrm, this is just a small program, I was unaware encapsulation would help here.

Comment: One problem is given by `g++ -Wall -Wextra` (and only one; not bad!) as: `obst.cpp: In function ‘void PrintTableFile()’:
obst.cpp:43:34: warning: array subscript is above array bounds [-Warray-bounds]`.  This derives from the array access in `for (int i = 0; i <= n; ++i) { outfile<< setw(10) << A[i]; }`.  Since you define `char A[n] = ...;`, the condition in the loop should be `i < n` (not `i <= n`).

Comment: I have changed that, thank you. I will have to look into how to have my compiler tell me if i'm out of bounds.  That however, did not fix the main problem.

Comment: In all honesty, I never expected it to be the whole problem; that's why it is a comment.  I get to see ASCII NUL characters in my output file.  This is, I think, the problem that @msnider diagnosed.  With his fix in place, the code seemed to work sanely.  Give him the accept (and up-vote).  Also, please check up on how to write an SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)) .  Also, you should make `outfile` a local variable in `main()` and pass it to the called functions, so you can open and close the file in a single function (`main()`).  Avoid globals; they're bad.

Comment: Yes, I completely understand that.  I will look that up, but I will say that I would not usually write this in this manner...and I guess I never should.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is almost certainly a problem with the way you are tracking your recursion depth.

```
outfile.write("",space);
```

Here you are telling the `write()` function to print `space` characters of the empty string `""`. Up to a certain level, this appears to work fine (e.g. the `Ì` always occurs at a depth of 5 for the output you supplied).

If you look it up, [`ostream& write (const char* s, streamsize n)`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/write/) is meant to have as its first argument an array of **at least** `n` characters, and its second argument is the number of characters to write. Instead you should do something like this:

```
outfile << std::string(spaces, ' ') << '-' << std::endl;
```

Which will create and write a new string of whitespace with length `spaces` to the `outfile` stream.

Comment: Yes, that definitely fixed it.  I read about the write() function several times and missed that point...not very bright of me.  Thank you very much.

Comment: As a side note...may I get either a reference or short answer as to why the write() function works until the recursive depth reaches 4-5.  If you know off-hand.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure. 

If I execute `std::cout.write("", 100)`, I get similar behavior. It seems to print 4 `NUL`s before printing other nonsense characters. Then it prints "Mingw runtime failure: VirtualQuery failed for %d bytes at address %p". It looks like some sort of undefined behavior causing the .text portion of the [object file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_file) to get printed. 

@user2079828 I'm curious as to what happens when you write more than 4-6 characters of the `""` empty string.